# I am using MYSQL with the EXTRACTVALUE command, and the below query returns BLANK when using the [@attribute="value"] filter. Why?

Tags: mysql, xml

Here is my sample xml:

```
<GS-Pay>
<index>
<year>2017</year>
<Step-One>28000</Step-One>
<Step-Two>45000</Step-Two>
</index>
<index>
<year>2018</year>
<Step-One>30000</Step-One>
<Step-Two/>
</index>
<index>
<year>2019</year>
<Step-One>50000</Step-One>
<Step-Two>60000</Step-Two>
</index>
<total> </total>
</GS-Pay>
```

Here is my query

```
EXTRACTVALUE(@xml,'//GS-Pay//index//Step-One[@year="2017"]')
```

Here is the result:

```
BLANK
```

Here is what I need:

```
28000
```

Edit:

When I query

```
EXTRACTVALUE(@xml,'//worksheet//GS-Pay//index//Step-One')
```

The results show fine,

```
28000 30000 50000
```

I just need the ability to filter it based on another node value.

Comment: also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. As the `EXTRACTVALUE(@xml,'//worksheet//GS-Pay//index//Step-One')` does not match up with a XML example you shown..

Comment: okay that's good information

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE('<GS-Pay>
<index>
<year>2017</year>
<Step-One>28000</Step-One>
<Step-Two>45000</Step-Two>
</index>
<index>
<year>2018</year>
<Step-One>30000</Step-One>
<Step-Two/>
</index>
<index>
<year>2019</year>
<Step-One>50000</Step-One>
<Step-Two>60000</Step-Two>
</index>
<total> </total>
</GS-Pay>','/GS-Pay/index[year[text()=2017]]/Step-One/text()') value;
```

Gives  you  the wanted

```
value    
28000
```

It took me a while, because only the simple extraction are explained.